# C++ Nested For Loops incrementation

Tags: c++

Somehow my first for loop is incrementing first so that the output is as follows:

```
map<int, vector<int>> inputs;

vector<int> vec1 = {1,2,3};
vector<int> vec2 = {1,2,3};
vector<int> vec3 = {1,2,3};

for (int a = 0; a < vec1.size(); a++) 
{
    for (int b = 0; b < vec2.size(); b++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < vec3.size(); c++)
        {
            int key = a + b + c;
            vector<int> vals = { vec1[a], vec2[b], vec3[c] };
            inputs[key] = vals;
        }
    }
}

for (const auto &v : inputs)
{
    cout << v.first << ": ";
    for (int vv : v.second) cout << vv << "  ";
    cout << '\n';
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
0: 1  1  1  
1: 2  1  1  
2: 3  1  1  
3: 3  2  1  
4: 3  3  1  
5: 3  3  2  
6: 3  3  3
```

I was expecting the output to be in order:

```
0: 1  1  1  
1: 1  1  2  
2: 1  1  3  
3: 1  2  1  
4: 1  2  2  
5: 1  2  3  
6: 1  3  1
7: 1  3  2
8: 1  3  3 
9: 2  1  1
...
```

Why is vec1 `a` incrementing first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int keys` will overwrite itself giving the illusion that `a` is increasing first.

My solution to the problem is:

```
map<int, vector<int>> inputs;

vector<int> vec1 = {1,2,3};
vector<int> vec2 = {1,2,3};
vector<int> vec3 = {1,2,3};
int k = 0;

for (int a = 0; a < vec1.size(); a++) 
{
    for (int b = 0; b < vec2.size(); b++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < vec3.size(); c++)
        {
            vector<int> vals = { vec1[a], vec2[b], vec3[c] };
            inputs[k] = vals;
            k++;
        }
    }
}

for (const auto &v : inputs)
{
    cout << v.first << ": ";
    for (int vv : v.second) cout << vv << "  ";
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I guess I went code blind there. Will accept. Have a great weekend. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your three vectors contains the combinations

```
1 1 2
1 2 1
2 1 1
```

All three of them will result in the sum `4`, which will be used for the key in the map. A map can only have *one* or each key, and its value will be the last one assigned to it. So `inputs[4]` will have the last vector assigned to it, which is the `2 1 1` combination.

If you want all combinations then you need to use a vector instead:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> inputs;

...

inputs.push_back(vals);
```

Or if you're required to use a map, then create a new variables that you increase for each insertion into the map, making each entry have a unique key.